# how to put adwords code in ajax query method in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-ads-api

```
var $Form = $("#Form").validate({
    rules: {
        Name: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        Name: {
            required: 'Please enter your name',
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#SubmitButton').addClass('disabled');
        $.ajax({
            url: "Folder/AjaxFile.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#SubmitButton').removeClass('disabled');
                if (data.error === undefined) {
                    $(form)[0].reset();
                    $('#SuccessMsg').html(data.success);
                } else {
                    $('#ProjectFailureMsg').html(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
});
```

I am using above method to validate form and submit form via ajax. In this form i want to apply Google AdWords Code. 
How should i implement Adwords code in this Ajax ?
My Adwords code is like below.

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXX'); 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to only call the code on a successful submission, or just when the page loads? If it's the latter, just drop the code in either on the page itself, or in the js file without the script tags. If it's the former, then just drop it into the success function.

Comment: @aynber - I want to run that adwords code on ajax call function.

Comment: Then place the code (without the script tags) wherever you want it to run.